# Is it possible to connect a computer using HTTP Protocol?

Tags: http, networking, ip-address, http-protocols

Let us see I have a

> GSM Modem

connected to a `computer that having a valid Static IP Address`. Now as a PHP Developer i want to `connect to that computer and have to listen the COM1 port`. This is what exactly i'm looking for.

Is this possible ?

Comment: @James I think you could create a GUI in Visual Basic to do it.

Comment: assuming that you really don't want to make fun of the people that try to help you, you should describe in more detail what you want to do. So far it is pretty unclear - to me at least.

Comment: @BNL excellent idea. Solves most problems IP related! http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=hkDD03yeLnU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are writing about is always done when you hit some page by your browser ;-) Exactly your computer connects to the web server using HTTP protocol. So I guess that you are looking for something like remote desktop over HTTP? So AFAIK you have two options Write your own web server/client software to do this task or you can do some kine of tunneling (if it is just meter of the open ports/protocols).

Comment: Hey guys, This is the real question what i want exactly. **Connecting a modem attached to COM1 port outside the network**

Comment: I Concluded that A connection via made using **Port Forwarding** which depends on a router. Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 1):

```
telnet {remote_computer's_ip_address} 80
telnet> get /
```